# How to make Appium clean app before scenario

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, appium

I use Appium along with JUnit. Also Cucumber, but his one shouldn't interfere here.

I need to have clear app installation every case to make them really independent. I use following IOSDriver settings:

```
    public static void initDriver(boolean noReset) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 4s");
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", noReset);
        capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts",true);
        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

   public void quitDriver() {
        driver.executeScript("au.backgroundApp(0)");
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
```

### @Before problem

What I do is I check if the app is installed before every case, and if it is, to reinstall it. Unfortunately, when I uninstall the app, session is broken and the test case fails.

**EDIT:** initDriver() method causes the driver to start and install the app automatically, so this `if(isAppInstalled)` part is executed even when the app is not installed on device previously.

```
     @Before
        public void beforeScenario() throws MalformedURLException {
            initDriver(false);
            if(IosConfig.getDriver().isAppInstalled(StringConfiguration.getiOSappBundleId())) {
                System.out.println("THE APP IS INSTALLED. UNINSTALLING...");
                IosConfig.getDriver().removeApp(StringConfiguration.getiOSappBundleId());
            }
       }
```

### @After problem [solved]

Moreover, my @After part is not executed, so the app is not uninstalled after the case...

```
@After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        try {
            if(scenario.isFailed()) {
                final byte[] screenshot = IosConfig.getDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
                IosConfig.getDriver().closeApp();
          IosConfig.getDriver().removeApp(StringConfiguration.getiOSappBundleId());
            }
        } finally {
            IosConfig.getDriver().closeApp();
         IosConfig.getDriver().removeApp(StringConfiguration.getiOSappBundleId());
            quitDriver();

        }
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: Try fullReset = true in capabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with "After" part solved.

I use also Cucumber, and by mistake I imported `org.junit.After` instead of `cucumber.api.java.After`! That one was hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

1. In @Aftermethod you can call driver.resetApp()

   @AfterMethod
     public void resetApp(){
         if(null != driver){
             driver.resetApp();
         }
     }
2. If this is not working for you use  fullReset  = true in capabilities